# How to put InAppPurchase settings in settings bundle?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, settings.bundle

I'm trying to add in app purchase to my app. According to apple's documentation, I have to implement my own purchase view or related stuff.

And currently in my app, I've used Settings.Bundle to implement the setting items, and I want to add IAP button here, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, settings is only a fixed set of controls, there's no logic to load, validate and process your purchases. You will have to write your own UI for that.

Comment: I guess so.. Thanks anyway!